# What is an Efficient Algorithm to find Graph Centroid?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search, centroid, connected-components

Graph Centroid is a vertex at equal distance or at distance less than or equal (N/2) where N is the size of the connected components connected through this vertex?! [Needs Correction?!]

Here's a problem at CodeForces that asks to find whether each vertex is a centroid, but after removing and replacing exactly one edge at a time.

[Problem Statement](http://codeforces.com/contest/709/problem/E)

I need help to refine this PseudoCode / Algorithm.

```
Loop all Vertices:
 Loop all edges:
  Position each edge in every empty edge position between two unconnected nodes
  Count Size of each Connected Component (*1).
  If all sizes are less than or equal N/2,
   Then return true
```

The problem is that this algorithm will run in at least O(N*M^2)). It's not acceptable.

I looked up the answers, but I couldn't come up with the high level abstraction of the algorithm used by others. Could you please help me understand how these solutions work?

[Solutions' Link](http://codeforces.com/contest/709/status/E)

(*1) [DFS Loop](https://github.com/thecortex/C-Practice-2016b/blob/master/Centroids/main.cpp)

Comment: Be careful the code force problem is only about trees and not general graphs.

Comment: Can you please pseudo-code the algorithm used in these solutions file at a high-level?

Comment: There are about 150 accepted submissions, and none of those I checked bothered much with documentation...

Comment: Not a full algorithm, just an idea: The problem statement asks for one edge replacement. Since the graphs are trees, each connected component will be a tree, also. By removing any edge and adding a new edge, you can move an arbitrary number of vertices form one component to another, so you "just" have to check whether there is at most one component with more than n/2 nodes, and if there is, that there is another component such that the two combined have at most n nodes.

Comment: Correction: Depending on the layout of the component, it may not always be possible to find an edge to cut off any number of nodes, but the general idea should still be valid.

Comment: Thank you @tobias_k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to describe you a not so complex algorithm for solving this problem in linear time, for future references see my [code](http://codeforces.com/contest/708/submission/20402431) (it have some comments).

The main idea is that you can root the tree T at an arbitrary vertex and traverse it, for each vertex V you can do this:

- Cut subtree V from T.
- Find the heaviest vertex H having size <= N/2 (H can be in any of T or subtree V).
- Move subtree H to become child of subtree V.
- Re root T with V and find if the heaviest vertex have size <= N/2

The previous algorithm can be implemented carefully to get linear time complexity, the issue is that it have a lot of cases to handle.

A better idea is to find the centroid C of T and root T at vertex C.

Having vertex C as the root of T is useful because it guarantee us that every descendant of C have size <= N/2.

When traversing the tree we can avoid to check for the heaviest vertex down the tree but up, every time we visit a child W, we can pass the heaviest size (being <= N/2) if we re root T at W.

Try to understand what I explained, let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: Thank you, I will follow this approach, and I hope it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Well, the Centroid of a tree can be determined in O(N) space and time complexity.**

1. Construct a Matrix representing the Tree, with the row indexes representing the N nodes and the elements in the i-th row representing the nodes to which i-th node is connected. You can any other representation also.
2. Maintain 2 linear arrays of size N with index i representing the depth of i-th node (depth) and the parent of the i-th node (parent) respectively.
3. Also maintain 2 more linear arrays, the first one containing the BFS traversal sequence of the tree (queue), and the other one (leftOver) containing the value of **[N - Number of nodes in the subtree rooted at that node]**. In other words, the i-th index contains the number of nodes that is left in the whole tree when the i-th node is removed from the tree along with all its children.
4. Now, perform a BFS traversal taking any arbitrary node as root and fill the arrays 'parent' and 'depth'. This takes O(N) time complexity. Also, record the traversal sequence in the array 'queue'.
5. Starting from the leaf nodes, add the number of nodes present in the subtree rooted at that node, with the value at the parent index in the array 'leftOver'. This also takes O(N) time since you can use the already prepared 'queue' array and travel from backwards.
6. Finally, traverse through the array 'leftOver' and modify each value to [N-1 - Initial Value]. The 'leftOver' array is prepared. Cost: Another O(N).
7. Your work is almost done. Now, iterate over this 'leftOver' array and find the index whose value is closest to floor(N/2). However, this value must not exceed floor(N/2) at any cost.

This index is the index of the Centroid of the Tree. Overall time complexity: O(N).

**Java Code**:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Find_Centroid
{
    static final int MAXN=100_005;
    static ArrayList<Integer>[] graph;
    static int[] depth,parent;  // Step 2
    static int N;

    static Scanner io=new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i;
        N=io.nextInt();
                    // Number of nodes in the Tree
        graph=new ArrayList[N];

        for(i=0;i<graph.length;++i)
            graph[i]=new ArrayList<>();
                    //Initialisation

        for(i=1;i<N;++i)
        {
            int a=io.nextInt()-1,b=io.nextInt()-1;
                    // Assuming 1-based indexing
            graph[a].add(b);    graph[b].add(a);
                    // Step 1
        }
        int centroid = findCentroid(new java.util.Random().nextInt(N));
                    // Arbitrary indeed... ;)

        System.out.println("Centroid: "+(centroid+1));
                    // '+1' for output in 1-based index
    }

    static int[] queue=new int[MAXN],leftOver;
                    // Step 3

    static int findCentroid(int r)
    {
        leftOver=new int[N];
        int i,target=N/2,ach=-1;

        bfs(r);     // Step 4
        for(i=N-1;i>=0;--i)
            if(queue[i]!=r)
                leftOver[parent[queue[i]]] += leftOver[queue[i]] +1;
                    // Step 5
        for(i=0;i<N;++i)
            leftOver[i] = N-1 -leftOver[i];
                    // Step 6
        for(i=0;i<N;++i)
            if(leftOver[i]<=target && leftOver[i]>ach)
                    // Closest to target(=N/2) but does not exceed it.
            {
                r=i;    ach=leftOver[i];
            }
                    // Step 7
        return r;
    }
    static void bfs(int root)   // Iterative
    {
        parent=new int[N];  depth=new int[N];
        int st=0,end=0;
        parent[root]=-1;    depth[root]=1;
                // Parent of root is obviously undefined. Hence -1.
                // Assuming depth of root = 1
        queue[end++]=root;
        while(st<end)
        {
            int node = queue[st++], h = depth[node]+1;
            Iterator<Integer> itr=graph[node].iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext())
            {
                int ch=itr.next();
                if(depth[ch]>0)     // 'ch' is parent of 'node'
                    continue;
                depth[ch]=h;   parent[ch]=node;
                queue[end++]=ch;    // Recording the Traversal sequence
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, for the problem, http://codeforces.com/contest/709/problem/E, iterate over each node i, consider it as the root, keep descenting down the child which has >N/2 nodes and try to arrive at a node which has just less than N/2 nodes (closest to N/2 nodes) under it. If, on removing this node along with all its children makes 'i' the centroid, print '1' otherwise print 0. This process can be carried out efficiently, as the 'leftOver' array is already there for you.

Actually, you are detaching the disturbing node (the node which is preventing i from being the centroid) along with its children and attaching it to the i-th node itself. The subtree is guaranteed to have atmost N/2 nodes (as checked earlier) and so won't cause a problem now.

Happy Coding..... :)